# Haskell: How to subtract numbers in a list with foldr?

Tags: haskell

when you add numbers in a list with foldr it works:

```
sumIntegers :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumIntegers xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

but to substract doesn't work the same way because 
minus minus = plus. [2,3,4,5] is like: 2-3+4-5.

```
subtractNums' :: Num a => [a] -> a
subtractNums' xs = foldr (-) 0 xs

subtractNums :: Num a => [a] -> a
subtractNums []     = 0
subtractNums (x:xs) = x - subtractNums xs
```

What has to be changed?
thank you in advance

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh I did´t suspect that its that simple, thank you!

Comment: when its foldl instead of foldr it works:) `subtractNums' xs = foldl (-) 0 `

Comment: Addition is associative; subtraction is not.

Comment: Basically you have to keep in mind that if the result of the folding function is of the same type with the items of the list that you are feeding with, then you might use `foldl1` or `foldlr1` instead. So no need for an accumulator here. But yes... when the function is `(-)` the result changes according to from which end you start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addition is associative (and commutative, meaning it doesn't matter if the identity gets added first on the right, or last on the left), so both `foldr` and `foldl` compute the same sum:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3] == 1 + (2 + (3 + 0)) == 1 + 2 + 3 == 6
foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] == ((0 + 1) + 2) + 3 == 1 + 2 + 3 == 6
```

However, subtraction is *not* associative; `(x - y) - z` does not, in general, equal `x - (y - z)`, so `foldr` and `foldl` compute two different results:

```
foldl (-) 0 [1,2,3] == ((0 - 1) - 2) - 3 
                    == (-1 - 2) - 3 
                    == -3 - 3
                    == -6
foldr (-) 0 [1,2,3] == 1 - (2 - (3 - 0)) 
                    == 1 - (2 - 3)
                    == 1 - -1
                    == 2
```

Which function you choose depends on which running difference you actually want to compute.

Comment: Shouldn't `foldl'` be used instead of `foldl`? `foldl` is too much viable of memory exhaustion.

Comment: Probably, but that's beyond the scope of the question. I'm not advocating the use of either function, just explaining the differences between them.